# Creating Strapi Repeatable Components

Tags: reactjs, next.js, strapi

I find creating repeatable components in Strapi strange and confusing. To add a new component on Strapi, I use the following steps:

```
1. Click on Content-Type Builder
2. Under Components sub-section, click on Create new component
3. On the create new component dialogue box, insert the component Display name name and select or create a new category for the component.
4. Click Continue...
```

What I expect to see on the next page is to select if the component will be a repeatable component or a single component. Instead, I am presented with a set of fields to add to the component. To add a repeatable, I have to add another component to the component I just created. I am honestly confused with the whole process. Is this how its supposed to be?

Comment: The `repeatable` is a property of attribute. Basically you can make component repeatable when you add it somewhere

Comment: I created a component and added a title field. Now I added a dynamic field to one of my new single types and attempted adding the component as a repeatable but its not working. To add a component as a repeatable, I did this:
```
1. On the Content-Type builder page, I clicked on one of my single types and added a new dynamic zone.
2. Added a dynamic zone name and proceeded to add a component.
3. I tried to use an existing component, but once I click on Use an existing component and select the component, all I see is a finish button. No place to set selected component as repeatable
```

Comment: Dynamiczone is repeatable by default, any component you add there you can repeat as many times you want